# Keynote 6.6.2, iMac, OS El Capitan: How do I export Keynote presentation to quicktime without the voice over?

Tags: audio, video, keynote, quicktime, garageband

I created a Keynote slide show.
I created the 'audio' for the presentation using Garageband.
I then dropped the audio into my Keynote presentation.
Then I recorded the slideshow to time the slides to my audio file.

Now... when I try to export to Quicktime, it includes both my audio file AS WELL AS the 'voice over narration' that was included when I recorded.
(Basically, it's my mic picking up the audio from the presentation as a I recorded it so it's like an echo and it sounds terrible.)

I looked in the forum and in 2009 someone asked a similar question. The answer was:
Remove the voice narration when exporting to quicktime.

However, there doesn't seem to be that option in the latest version of Keynote.

Does anyone know the answer to this?

Let me know if you need a screenshot or screencast for further clarification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions, the first one is to export to QuickTime with the audio and then remove the audio the secondary is to first remove the audio then export to QuickTime.

**Solution 1** 
First export to QuickTime 
Open iMovie and create a new movie project (you can remove the new project later)
Drag and drop the video file to the large grey section at the bottom
Right click and click Detach audio
Right click on the new green bar below and click Delete (all audio has been removed)
To export, Click File->Share->File and click next and save it where you will find it.

Note, this solution removes all the audio. If you would like to keep some, you can simply add the audio just before you export the file in iMovie by drawing it to the large grey section.

**Solution 2** 
An audio file in a keynote looks like this:
[image: Image of icon]
They are placed on the slides and don't have any fixed positions so they can be located at anywhere. To remove them you have to look thru all the slides and remove them one by one. Click on it then press backspace to remove it.

Comment: thanks so much! I'll try the iMovie approach. That might be easiest. The other way... isn't working. When I play the slides in Keynote, it sounds fine - there's no 'double' recording. It's only when I play 'recorded slideshow' that I get the double recording.. and that unfortunately is what gets exported. (The little audio icon as picture on your screenshot doesn't show up on my version of keynote.)

Comment: You may find it buried under other elements.  For example behind a picture or video on a slide.